# DatePicker sets date several years forwards/backwards on click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I'm trying to select a date period using two datepickers (from bootstrap4), but when I press the button to open the picker, it changes the model's current date to either a date 1 year ahead or several years back compared to the current date.

I've implemented the datepicker with javascript (two ways for trying to find out how to fix the bug):

First datepicker where I tried with different settings:

```
<script>
    $('#datepickerStart').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
            autoclose: true,
            format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
            immediateUpdates: true,
            todayBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        }).datepicker("setDate", "01/01/2020");
</script>
```

Second datepicker, which is how I originally implemented it:

```
<script>
    $('#datepickerEnd').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        "setDate": new Date(),
        "autoclose": true
    });
</script>
```

This is what it looks like when I use the code:

[image]

The end date field first looks like the start date field (i.e. "24-03-2020"), but when I press the picker button to open the calendar, it automatically inserts the date 12/03/2021 in the field and goes to december in the calendar..

This is the viewmodel attributes used:

```
public string PeriodStart { get; set; }
public string PeriodEnd { get; set; }
```

I've tried:

- Changing the attributes to DateTime
- Formatting the string so it fits the mm/dd/yyyy format ('/' instead of '-')

What am I missing here? It seems like it does not use the settings I set for the datepicker, how do I make it use them?

These are the elements im trying to use the datepicker on:

```
        <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
            @Html.Label("Start Date")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PeriodStart, new { id = "datepickerStart" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
            @Html.Label("End Date")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PeriodEnd, new { id = "datepickerEnd" })
        </div>
```

**Edit**
These are the .js and .css files used:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Taken from this example: https://gijgo.com/datepicker/example/bootstrap-4

**Updated with gif**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYyLO.jpg

Comment: set the format accepted by the datepicker plugin - since this is really about that, it would help to know WHICH datepicker .js file (including version) is in use here - there are many

Comment: I'm using the built-in datepicker from Bootstrap 4.4 (there's no datepicker.js file in my project) I've updated the post with the .js and .css sources i'm using for the datepicker.

Comment: Please elaborate why this is not correct for your situation  https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format  if you actually use the format you specify `"01-01-2020"` here `format: "mm-dd-yyyy",`

Comment: I've made a gif showing the problem, I do not know how else to explain my issue. https://imgur.com/YstzXoY

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In my method, where I create my ViewModel, I set the initial date to the current date, which messed the datepicker up (most likely because of formatting, as Mark Schultheiss suggested).

I removed the code seen below and now the datepicker opens at the current date.

```
viewModel.PeriodStart = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
viewModel.PeriodStart = viewModel.PeriodStart.Substring(0, 10);
```